# Python Selenium IE - Clicking on an anchor does not change the URL

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, anchor

### As Short As Possible

I am trying to do test automation using Python with py.test and Selenium.

I have tried two approaches to change the URL by clicking an anchor `<a>` element, neither of the approaches seems to work - the URL does not change.

There are no errors reported, other than the incorrect assertion result.

The element I want to click on is:

```
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="crumb in bcCtrl.data">
<!-- ngIf: !$last -->
<a class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="!$last" ng-href="#/accounts/8" href="#/accounts/8">RC München</a>
<!-- end ngIf: !$last -->
<!-- ngIf: $last -->
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: crumb in bcCtrl.data -->
```

#### What I have checked so far

- I can find the anchor,
- The anchor found is the correct one (has the correct text, and href)
- (using JScript) That doing .click() on the anchor indeed causes the page to load the new URL just like the user action would

#### First approach

The first approach was to use:

```
pre_last_breadcrumb_element = self.find_elements_by_locator(locators['breadcrumb_elements'])[-1]
pre_last_breadcrumb_element.click()
```

but this seems not to have done anything.

#### Second approach

The second approach was to use:

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
el = self.find_elements_by_locator(locators['breadcrumb_elements'])[-1]
actions.move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()
```

But still no desired result.

What am I doing wrong? Please help...

---

### More details

The code that I've used is:

```
pre_last_breadcrumb_element = self.find_elements_by_locator(locators['breadcrumb_elements'])[-1]
# this will click the pre-last element in the breadcrumb
print("PreLast = {0}".format(pre_last_breadcrumb_element.text))
print("BEFORE CLICK get_current_url='{0}'".format(self.driver.get_current_url))

# APPROACH 1
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
el = self.find_elements_by_locator(locators['breadcrumb_elements'])[-1]
actions.move_to_element(el).click(el).perform()
# FIXME: The click on the anchor does not work...

# APPROACH 2
# pre_last_breadcrumb_element.click()
# FIXME: The click on the anchor does not work...

print("AFTER  CLICK get_current_url='{0}'".format(self.driver.get_current_url))
# checking if the pre-last element changed due to the click
print("PreLast = {0}".format(pre_last_breadcrumb_element.text))
print("Changing between URLs\nFROM:'{0}'\n  TO:'{1}'".format(self.get_url, pre_last_breadcrumb_element.get_attribute("href")))

# this will reload the page class at the newer URL
self.open_at_current_location()
print("Current URL:'{0}'".format(self.get_url))
assert last_breadcrumb_element.text is pre_last_breadcrumb_element.text
```

This is the result:

```
PreLast = RC München
BEFORE CLICK get_current_url='http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/9'
AFTER  CLICK get_current_url='http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/9'
PreLast = RC München
Changing between URLs
FROM:'http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/9'
  TO:'http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/8'
get_current_url='http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/9'
Current URL:'http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/9'
```

Comment: What happens when you click the element in the browser yourself? This is probably because any url that's `example.com/page/#/any/thing` is always the same page as `example.com/page` -- The difference is that a web framework can parse the extranious parts of the request URL to determine what content to deliver. Rather than clicking the element, you can also try pulling the `href` value, joining it to the current URL, then using `driver.get(new_location)`

Comment: Try once as `driver.find_element_by_link_text("RC München").click()` and let me know

Comment: @SaurabhGaur - using `# APPROACH 4
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("RC München").click()` - again, nothing happened

Comment: @Gator_Python - when I click the element myself I get redirected to the correct URL - that is to `http://fct:8080/fct/#/accounts/8`, which is also the `href` value.
I would prefer to avoid going the `driver.get(new_location)` way if possible

I have also made a bit of a wicked experiment - added a `time.sleep(5)` to manually click the link ... and it didn't work. Now I am completely baffled...

Comment: Ok, try once using `execute_script()` as `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("RC München"))` and see what happens..

Comment: There is probably some JS event listeners on that anchor that looks for a mousedown & mouseup or something of that nature. I don't believe selenium actually replicates that with `.click()` Can you see what JavaScript is executing when you click it? In your network inspector, this would be the `initiator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've tried all but nothing get success, you can try using [`WebDriver#execute_script()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) as an alternate solution where you can execute some piece of `JavaScript` code on the desired element to perform `click` as below :-

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("RC München")

#now click on this element using JavaScript 
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)
```

**Warning** :- The `JavaScript` injection `HTMLElement.click()` shouldn't be used in a testing context. It defeats the purpose of the test. First because it doesn't generate all the events like a real `click (focus, blur, mousedown, mouseup...)` and second because it doesn't guarantee that a real user can interact with the element.

But some time due to designing or other issues this is to be only solution, so you can consider it as an alternate solution.

Comment: This did work. However I will keep trying to make it work properly.
Thanks for the workaround!